# Beautiful Soup: Only target elements if a specific child has a certain class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm doing some python/beautiful soup exercises for practice, and I've run into a problem I'm struggling to solve: **I want to iterate over a series of tags, but only scrape the contents if it contains a child tag with a specific class**.

I'm parsing a page with sports scores, finding all `<section class="game">` tags and scraping the tables within. The issue is I only want to target the `<section>` tags that have a `<div>` inside with `class="game-status final "` applied. (The space after "final" is deliberate; that's how it is on the page.)

Here's an example of what the HTML looks like:

```
<section class="game">
    <h3>Team No. 1 vs Team No. 2</h3>
    <div class="game-contents">
        <div class="game-status final ">Final</div>
        <div class="game-championship"></div>
        <div class="linescore">
            <table class="linescore">
                <!-- TABLE CONTENTS -->
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="links final "></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Before the game goes final, the first `div` under `div.game-contents` is `<div class="game-status">`, so this is why I want to check this tag to determine if the game is final — and therefore should be scraped.

Here's the code I have for scraping those tables:

```
games = soup.find_all('section', class_='game')

list_of_games = []
for game in games:
    list_of_rows = []
    rows = game.find_all('tr')[1:]
    for row in rows:
        list_of_cells = []
        cells = row.find_all('td')
        for cell in cells:
            if 'school' in cell.attrs['class']:
                team = cell.find('a').text
                list_of_cells.append(team)
            elif 'final' in cell.attrs['class']:
                score = cell.text
                list_of_cells.append(score)
        list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)
    list_of_games.append(list_of_rows)
```

Obviously I will need to introduce new logic to determine if the `<section>` has the right properties before it's scraped, but I'm drawing a blank as to the best way to proceed.

Any help or guidance here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the `div` with `final` class and, if it is `None`, skip this row:

```
games = soup.find_all('section', class_='game')

list_of_games = []
for game in games:
    if game.find("div", class_="final") is None:
        continue
    # rest of the code
```

Comment: Quick and easy. Perfect. Thank you!